# Radio buttons, find if hide, show or delete were clicked and carrying out the operation

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button

I have a simple form the shows entries from a mysql db, each entry has a group of radio buttons - hide, show and delete. As my code stands now , nothing happens when i submit the form.

here is my form code

```
<form class='removeform' action='advertremoveedit.php' method='post'>
  <?php
  include '../inc/connect.php';
  $q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM adverts ORDER BY id ASC");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $q )){
    echo"<input type='radio' name='edit[{$row['id']}]' value='remove'>Remove";
    if ($row['status'] ==  1){
      echo"<input type='radio' name='edit[{$row['id']}]' value='hide'>Hide";
    }
  }
    echo"<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />";
  ?>
</form>
```

And here is the php to handle the form

```
if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
  $chk = (array) $_POST['remove'];
  $p = implode(',',array_keys($chk)); 
  $t = "SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE id IN ($p)";
  $result = $link->query($t);
  $url=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $image=$url['file']; 
  if ($result){
    unlink($image);
    $q = "DELETE FROM adverts WHERE id IN ($p)";
    $delete = $link->query($q);
  }
}

//if hide was clicked, change `status` to 1
if(isset($_POST['show'])){
  $edit= $_POST['show'];
  $chk = (array) $_POST['show'];
  $p = implode(',',array_keys($chk)); 
  $t = "SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE id IN ($p)";
  $result = $link->query($t);
  if ($result){
    $q = "UPDATE adverts SET status = 1 WHERE id IN ($p)";
    $show = $link->query($q);
  }
}
```

Edit..submit code

```
 if(isset($_REQUEST['edit'])){
    if($val=="hide"){
      $chk = (array) $_POST['hide'];
      $p = implode(',',array_keys($chk)); 
      $t = "SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE id = ($p)";
      $result = $link->query($t);
      if ($result){
        $q = "UPDATE adverts SET status = 2 WHERE id = ($p)";
        $hide = $link->query($q);}}}
```

Comment: You are getting $_POST['remove'], which does not exist in your form. Is this your final code or you have some more stuff of code ?

Comment: This is it. I'm struggling on this. Its probably a simple thing to do too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

**form:**

```
<form class='removeform' action='advertremoveedit.php' method='post'>
  <?php
  include '../inc/connect.php';
  $q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM adverts ORDER BY id ASC");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $q )){
    echo"<input type='radio' name='edit[".$row['id']."]' value='remove'>Remove";
    if ($row['status'] ==  1){
      echo"<input type='radio' name='edit[".$row['id']."]' value='hide'>Hide";
    }
  }
    echo"<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />";
  ?>
</form>
```

**AND submit Page**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['edit']))
{
    $arr_submit = $_REQUEST['edit'];
    foreach($arr_submit as $id=>$val)
    {
        if($val=="remove")
        {
            // do your remove task for $id
        }
        else if($val=="hide")
        {
            // do you hide task for $id
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE : 2**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['edit']))
{
    $arr_submit = $_REQUEST['edit'];
    foreach($arr_submit as $id=>$val)
    {
        if($val=="remove")
        {
            // delete task on $id

              $t = "SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
              $result = $link->query($t);
              if($url=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
              {
                    $image=$url['file'];
                    $q = "DELETE FROM adverts WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
                    $delete = $link->query($q);
              }
        }
        else if($val=="hide")
        {
              $q = "UPDATE adverts SET status = 2 WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
              $show = $link->query($q);
        }
        else if($val=="show")
        {
              $q = "UPDATE adverts SET status = 1 WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
              $show = $link->query($q);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when i click hide i got this error Undefined index: hide

Comment: yes, ive edited my question to show the submit code im now using(hide shown only)

Comment: but in my answer of submit page there is no index of hide. check your page once again or put your submitpage

Comment: hide is the value of the radio button?

Comment: yes but not the index my dear and you get the error undefined index. let show me your updated submit page.

Comment: its in my question, at the bottom. ive only shown the code for the ['hide' function

Comment: it means you have not tried the code i have provide in submit. is tested try my update 2 in sumbit only

Comment: I have tried it, and put my 'hide' code into it? am i missing something?

Comment: sorry, i didnt see your update 2, will try this now!

Comment: ive tried your 2nd edit but now when i submit the form it takes me to an empty page!

Comment: scrub that, it works! of course it takes me to an empty submit page as i havent put any redirects in yet! i checked the db and everything is as expected. thanks a lot Satish

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem when binding arrays to an `IN` condition.

When you bind your `$p` ids into your query you get the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE id IN ('1,2,3');
```

Clearly there are no adverts that have the nonsensical id `'1,2,3'`!

You have 2 options:

1) Run a separate query for each value in `$p`.

2) Dynamically build the query with either the values concatenated directly or, as a preferred option, a dynamic number of placeholders and bind each value separately.